# A value in a list, python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Every character in the English language has a percentage of occurrence, these are the percentages:

```
A       B       C       D       E       F       G       H       I
.0817   .0149   .0278   .0425   .1270   .0223   .0202   .0609   .0697
J       K       L       M       N       O       P       Q       R
.0015   .0077   .0402   .0241   .0675   .0751   .0193   .0009   .0599
S       T       U       V       W       X       Y       Z   
.0633   .0906   .0276   .0098   .0236   .0015   .0197   .0007
```

A list called `letterGoodness` is predefined as:

```
letterGoodness = [.0817,.0149,.0278,.0425,.1270,.0223,.0202,...
```

I need to find the "goodness" of a string. For example the goodness of 'I EAT' is: .0697 + .1270 + .0817 + .0906 =.369. This is part of a bigger problem, but I need to solve this to solve the big problem. I started like this:

```
def goodness(message):
   for i in L:
     for j in i:
```

So it will be enough to find out how to get the occurrence percentage of any character. Can you help me?
The string contains only uppercase letters and spaces.

Comment: You have an array of length 26.  Each character in your string has an ascii number.  Write a method to convert the ascii number to the proper array index.  Then you can simply iterate over the string, summing the goodness values in O(n).

new edit: If your string is only uppercase letters, then yeah, a dictionary would remove the need for the hash function I described.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

letterGoodness is better as a dictionary, then you can just do:

```
sum(letterGoodness.get(c,0) for c in yourstring.upper())
#                                             #^.upper for defensive programming
```

To convert `letterGoodness` from your list to a dictonary, you can do:

```
import string
letterGoodness = dict(zip(string.ascii_uppercase,letterGoodness))
```

If you're guaranteed to only have uppercase letters and spaces, you can do:

```
letterGoodness = dict(zip(string.ascii_uppercase,letterGoodness))
letterGoodness[' '] = 0
sum(letterGoodness[c] for c in yourstring)
```

but the performance gains here are probably pretty minimal so I would favor the more robust version above.

---

If you insist on keeping `letterGoodness` as a list (and I don't advise that), you can use the builtin `ord` to get the index (pointed out by cwallenpoole):

```
 ordA = ord('A')
 sum(letterGoodness[ord(c)-ordA] for c in yourstring if c in string.ascii_uppercase)
```

I'm too lazy to `timeit` right now, but you may want to also define a temporary set to hold `string.ascii_uppercase` -- It might make your function run a little faster (depending on how optimized `str.__contains__` is compared to `set.__contains__`):

```
 ordA = ord('A')
 big_letters = set(string.ascii_uppercase)
 sum(letterGoodness[ord(c)-ordA] for c in yourstring.upper() if c in big_letters)
```

Comment: But don't forget to discard non-alphabetical characters.

Comment: ahh, I see you're browsing python questions today too. Beat me by 8 seconds and with code to boot. I might just come back tomorrow :D

Comment: To avoid the non-alphabetic problem, I'd use `letterGoodness.get(i.upper(), 0)` instead rather than doing the membership tests.

Comment: The string is only uppercase characters, I'll edit my post now, sorry.

Comment: @Reginald Practice defensive programming.

Comment: @DSM -- `.get` is better than my `in string.ascii_uppercase`.  good point. (Updated)

Comment: @cwallenpoole -- I was about to upvote your solution when you deleted it -- the idea was solid.  (although it didn't discard non-alphabetical characters either).

Comment: @cwallenpoole: you'd have to handle non-alphabetic characters anyway, though, as the OP's example string was `"I eat"`..

Comment: @mgilson Good! Then add it to yours. No sense in duplicate answers.

Comment: @DSM my example was kinda wrong, I had to write I EAT , I mentioned later that the string can me only uppercase characters or spaces.

Comment: Moved `.upper` to the string that is being iterated over to save multiple function calls.  I think it also makes the code slightly neater.

Comment: Thank you, now I finnaly understood how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You would be better off using a dictionary data structure.

EDIT: This is not my original code but instead the code updated along the lines DSM suggested.

```
import string

num_vals = [.0817, .0149, .0278, .0425, .1270, .0223, .0202, .0609, .0697 , .0015, .0077,
            .0402, .0241, .0675, .0751, .0193, .0009, .0599, .0633, .0906, .0276, .0098,
            .0236, .0015, .0197, .0007]

letterGoodness = {letter : value for letter,value in map(None, string.ascii_uppercase, num_vals)}

def goodness(message):
    string_goodness = 0
    for letter in message:
        letter = letter.upper()
        if letter in letterGoodness.keys():
            string_goodness += letterGoodness[letter]
    return string_goodness

print goodness("I eat")
```

Using the test case you provided:

```
print goodness("I eat")
```

yields the output:

```
.369
```

One thing to note - building a dictionary as is done here requires on Python 2.7+. The same thing can be accomplished in Python 2.6+ with the `dict()` constructor.

Comment: I can't put my finger on exactly what number of repeated lines I'd accept before I would abstract the duplication away, but I'm confident that twenty-six is above it.  I think most Python programmers would do something more like what @mgilson did, and look a little dubiously at this.

Comment: A valid comment. I abstracted the repetition myself using find/replace in my editor but that has no bearing on the code output - the result is not elegant.

Comment: `map(None,...)` is better written as `zip(...)`.

Comment: I'd never seen `zip(` written as `map(None,` ... Interesting.  Which came first?  `map` or `zip`?  This knowledge might be useful for python archeology...

Comment: @mgilson [http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html) lists  `zip()` with a _New in version 2.0_ while `map()` has no such qualifier so, assuming the omission is intentional, `map()` is the O.G. way to do it.